# Exercises database (for school, e.g. math problems)

Tags: exercises, database

I'm a math teacher to undergraduate level students in France.

I want to set up an efficient and easy to handle exercises database (written in LaTeX). I'm not so sure of the best way to proceed. I could possibly use the packages `xsim` and `exercise` or use a Python package (such as on https://github.com/supermihi/exdb).

What would you suggest?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Unfortunately your question is not really a good fit for the site, because it asks for an opinion on which package is the easiest/most efficient, and opinion-based questions are off-topic. However, you could try `xsim` which is well-documented and you can find many examples of using this package of the site.

Comment: Sorry for the typo (you should read "Exercises database")

Comment: @Marijn Maybe it is nevertheless good enough, in my humble opinion it's similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11 which is a very popular question with 100k+ views :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner that question is from 2010, when the criteria for what is on-topic were still being developed - such questions can still be useful but it is not really the best fit for the question/answer format.

Comment: Thank you both. Shall I rewrite the question without mentioning explicit packages ?

Comment: @Vincent a good way to write an on-topic question is to try one of the packages, find something that you want to do that you don't know how to do with that package, then write a minimal example, and ask a question 'I want to do this with the code below, how can I do it?' and then the answer can either be 'you can do it such-and-such with that package' or the answer could be 'this is not possible with the package but it can be done with other package X in such-and-such way'.

Comment: OK. I will try to figure this out. Nonetheless, I figure my question has quite an interest... not sure of it however...
Thanks, anyway !

Comment: If you are still in need you can take a look at https://github.com/CSMathematics/DataTex